# Questions regarding objects in java

Tags: java, object, null, immutability

I wanted answers for the below questions:

1) How can be objects in java made immutable?

2)  What are the different methods to make an object "null" in java?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html Read _"A Strategy for Defining Immutable Objects"_

Comment: An immutable object is an object whose state cannot be modified after it is created.

Comment: An objec can be made immutable she 1- it's contents can't be changed (private fields, no setter style methods) and 2- Anything that the object is given, when changed, isn't reflected by the object (it makes copies if the values). An object apcant be made null, only the references that point to the object can be bulled (or dereferenced)

Answer (score 1):

1) Fundamentally, you make an object immutable by disallowing modifications to its internal state after it is constructed.

2) You can't "make an object null", per se. You can, however, point a reference to null. I don't believe it gets much more idiomatic than `var = null`. Note that this does not change the object previously referred to by `var`, it just redirects `var` to point to `null`. It's important to think of Java variables in terms of references/pointers.